# Error while installing Goautodial in CentOS 7

Tags: centos, system-installation

I am trying to install Goautodial on my CentOS 7. while installing i have successfully completed the following steps.

1. Install minimal version of CentOS 5.X 64bit/32bit (CentOS 5.10 is latest as of this writing).
2. Install the GOautodial yum repository
   `# cd /etc/yum.repos.d/`
   `#wget http://downloads2.goautodial.org/centos/5/goautodial.repo`
3. Update system and install kernel development files
   `# yum update -y`
   `# yum install kernel-devel glibc-devel -y`

And at the 4th Step I got some Error.The fourth step is given below.

4. Install GOautodial applications and configurations
   `# yum -y install goautodial-ce goautodial-ce-config`

**The Errors are:**:

```
Finished Dependency   Resolution Error: Package: vicidial-2.9.441a-140612.1628.2.go.noarch (goautodial-current)  Requires: perl-Dahdi  Error: Package: vicidial-2.9.441a-140612.1628.2.go.noarch (goautodial-current)
           Requires: ploticus
Error: Package: vicidial-2.9.441a-140612.1628.2.go.noarch (goautodial-current)
           Requires: php-eaccelerator
Error: Package: vicidial-2.9.441a-140612.1628.2.go.noarch (goautodial-current)
           Requires: perl-String-CRC
Error: Package: vicidial-2.9.441a-140612.1628.2.go.noarch (goautodial-current)
           Requires: dkms-dahdi
Error: Package: vicidial-2.9.441a-140612.1628.2.go.noarch (goautodial-current)
           Requires: perl-Tk-TableMatrix
Error: Package: vicidial-2.9.441a-140612.1628.2.go.noarch (goautodial-current)
           Requires: htop
Error: Package: vicidial-2.9.441a-140612.1628.2.go.noarch (goautodial-current)
           Requires: perl-RPM-Specfile
Error: Package: vicidial-2.9.441a-140612.1628.2.go.noarch (goautodial-current)
           Requires: perl-Net-Address-IP-Local-0.1.2.tar.gz
Error: Package: vicidial-2.9.441a-140612.1628.2.go.noarch (goautodial-current)
           Requires: perl-Spreadsheet-Read
Error: Package: vicidial-2.9.441a-140612.1628.2.go.noarch (goautodial-current)
           Requires: perl-Net-Address-IPv4-Local
Error: Package: vicidial-2.9.441a-140612.1628.2.go.noarch (goautodial-current)
           Requires: perl-Spreadsheet-ReadSXC
Error: Package: vicidial-2.9.441a-140612.1628.2.go.noarch (goautodial-current)
           Requires: perl-Term-ReadLine-Gnu
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Somebody please help me to solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

The [instructions](http://goautodial.org/projects/goautodialce/wiki/64bit) you're following are written for CentOS 5, you'll need to use CentOS 5 for those instructions to work. BTW, CentOS 5  will be EOL March 31, 2017.

There is another repo for CentOS 7 at http://downloads2.goautodial.org/centos/7/goautodial.repo but it has some dependency failures on stuff like grub (el7 uses grub2), php-eaccelerator (project is dead), etc so it doesn't look like CentOS 7 support is there yet.

Comment: sorry it my mistake.Because there is only instruction for CentOS 5,i was just copying that instructions to post this question.I actually tried with  centOS 7 repo.but while doing so i got the above described errors.

Comment: So i can't use this on CentOS 7, right?

Comment: CentOS 5 AMI is not availiable in Amazon EC2. I am trying to deploy this on my Amazon EC2. So can you please suggest me other solutions.

Comment: @ARUNBALANNV you could create your own AMI if you really want to. Try asking on goautodial's forum since others might be having the same problem.